# How to construct a Turing Machine

Tags: turing-machines

Can someone help me to write a Turing Machine that decides whether its input  sentence is in a particular language or not? This particular 
language generates alternating 01's. If it decides the input is in the 
language it enters to the halting state 'y', otherwise it enters to the 
halting state 'n'.

Example sentences from that language: 010101 0101 0 01 010101010101
Example sentences not from that language: 110 0101011010101

Comment: Are strings from the target language allowed to start with $1$? Is $1010$ in your language? $101$?

Comment: Your language is regular. Construct a DFA for it, and convert it to a Turing machine.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that your tape alphabet is $\Sigma = \{0, 1, "\,"\}$, where the last character is a space. Also, it is not clear if a word in the language must start with a $0$ and end with a $1$. In the following I will assume so (it should be easy to modify the machine to remove one or both of these constraints).

The Turning Machine is $\langle \{y,n,q_0,q_1\}, \Sigma, \varepsilon, \Sigma, \delta, q_0, \{y,n\}  \rangle$, where:

- $\delta(q_0,0) = (q_1, 0, R)$,
- $\delta(q_0,1) = (n, 1, R)$,
- $\delta(q_0,"\,") = (q_0, "\,", R)$,
- $\delta(q_1,0) = (n, 0, R)$,
- $\delta(q_1,1) = (q_0, 1, R)$,
- $\delta(q_1,"\,") = (q_1, "\,", R)$,
- $\delta(q_0,\varepsilon) = (y, \varepsilon, R)$,
- $\delta(q_1,\varepsilon) = (n, \varepsilon, R)$.

Here state $q_0$ (resp. $q_1$) represents that, if the input word is in $L$, its next input character must be one of $\epsilon, 0, "\,"$ (resp. $\epsilon, 1, "\,"$).